# present features in the tree nodes in sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

Is there any method to present all the features in the resulted tree of the sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier , for examples if the csv files consists of 5 columns , then all the feature should appear in the resulted tree path.

example:

csv :

a,b,c,d,e

1,2,3,4,5

6,7,8,9,10

.....

then the a,b,c,d ranges should appear at least in one node in every tree path, is that possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand you need, but take a look here:
https://planetcalc.com/8443/

converts csv to tree by entropy
[image]